# How do I remove a bottle cap stuck 3 feet down a drain line

Tags: plumbing, drain, pipe, sewer, clog

A bottle cap (I think) fell down my sink drain and down the pipe before I could retrieve it.

It seems to be the perfect size to block the drain because despite no water down the drain for a month, there is water in the line.

I snaked the line, but it simply will not go any further down, I then put in an inspection camera but all I see is sandy water.

The drain pipe makes a 90 degree turn exactly when the clog is.

Any ideas? Is there a snake attachment that can drill into the cap (assuming that's what it is)? Is my only option to unscrew that section of pipe? (I have access to the bottom part where the 90 is.)

I googled for sewer vacuums to suck it out (or at least the water), but they don't seem to exist. I can't just attach the vacuum to the end of the drain since there is a vent - I'd have to insert something deep into the line.

This is the bottom of the pipe, you can't actually see the pipe in question here, it's inside the wall, but you can see the elbow.

[image: bottom of pipe]

This is the top of the pipe, where the sink goes.

[image: top of pipe in wall]

Comment: I wonder if you could try a magnet on a string?

Comment: @Matthew Most bottle caps I find these days are either plastic or aluminum - neither will be attracted by a magnet.

Comment: Try a shop vac with seal tight to sink drain. It may remove the water so you can see the blockage and it may also dislodge it

Comment: Maybe you could reach  it with a  Flex-Cable Pick-Up Tool 4-Finger Claw End Retriever Snake : https://www.amazon.com/X-Long-Flex-Cable-Pick-Up-4-Finger-Retriever/dp/B006ZEOXJY  (36" long)

Comment: After working on it for a long time with a scope and a snake, and some other tools, I'm convinced the blockage is at the end of the 90, and none of my tools seem able to navigate the turn.

Answer (score 4):

If the shop-vac suggestions in other answers don't do the trick, you may need to head to a local tool rental shop and pick up a commercial grade snake with a 1.5" head on it (to match the pipe diameter noted in a comment).

I've had to rent them a couple of times, and the ones I've gotten had a toothed, spiral head on them that should be able to cut through a plastic or even aluminum cap (they've done a fine job of cutting through tree roots, so plastic should be no problem at all, and it should cut into aluminum - it may not cut it up enough to slice it to pieces, but it may well get caught in the head and pull back out which is just as good). Usually these are powered, so they'll keep spinning when they hit an obstruction, and they're power fed so they'll keep pushing, too. You'll most likely want to remove the P-trap under the sink and go directly into the drain line and not try to feed it through the sink drain and the trap.

Be sure to specify to the guy at the counter what you're facing and they'll get you hooked up with the right thing.

Comment: What is needed is a snake with a spiral wire "head" that will screw into the cap.

Comment: @HotLicks I have one of those, but it did not screw in. It's not especially sharp.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to cut out (or unscrew - what type of pipe is this?) the elbow, and either remove the blockage or just replace the elbow - then add some couplings to put it back together (or screw it back together if it's threaded - though if it's old galvanized threaded, you might just want to replace it with plastic, as it may be badly corroded.)

You should also add some sort of strainer basket to your sink to prevent large objects from being able to fall into the drain.

Comment: I added photos of the pipe. It's cast iron, and probably original to the house, 100 years old. I do have a strainer, but someone temporarily removed it, I don't remember why.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify the size of the drain. But you can probably get some success by using a wet-dry vac and some kind of neck-down to a lower diameter, either a rigid pipe or a flexible hose.

Depending how the cap is stuck, the right answer might be to swallow it, using a bigger tube than the cap, or use a skinny flexible hose or tube and get it sucking on the inside of the cap, then pull it carefully back out.

Comment: It's 1.5 inch. I think the bottle cap is probably the same size as the pipe. I'll have to see if I can jury rig something to connect a small hose to a wet-dry vac.

Answer (score 0):

**Boiling water.**

Make use of the fact that this is a big cast iron pipe.

1. Remove as much existing water as you can.  Maybe shop vac with tube.
2. Fill cast iron pipe with boiling water.
3. Metal pipe will expand (a fair bit) and increase in diameter.  Maybe enough to dislodge blockage?  Hopefully it will move downstream far enough to encounter a bigger pipe.

If this doesn't work you are out the cost of some boiling water.  100C will not hurt a pipe like that.  If it works come back and post!

Comment: The drawback is that it might move a little bit further down the pipe, get stuck again, and now be even harder to reach.